# Page layout name via Rest Explorer in Workbench?

Tags: rest-api, api, page-layout, workbench

EDIT:

I'm trying to find this page layout in the workbench:

[image]
I'm attempting to get the page layout name for a given object via the rest explorer but I do not see the name, where do you look for it?

> /services/data/v40.0/sobjects/Opportunity/describe/layouts

Here is the screen shot of my workbench:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Tooling API. The REST API proper is designed to help render layouts on client devices, not get extra metadata such as the Layout Name. The URL would look like this:

```
/services/data/v40.0/tooling/query?q=SELECT+Id,Name+FROM+Layout+WHERE+TableEnumOrId%3D%27Opportunity%27
```

You'll query the [Layout](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_layout.htm) object, using the Tooling Query. You'll want to read the link for additional details on this object if you need it.

Since my Opportunity layout isn't interesting, here's my Lead layouts:

[image: Tooling API Example]

Comment: 1+ yep that's it.